# What is the etymology of 'cuius' and is it different from 'quis'?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, declension, pronouns, proto-indo-european

'cuius' (and 'cui') is an interesting word in that it stands out as different from the other terms in the declension of 'quis'.

It seems to be pronounced differently. 'quis' is /kwis/ but 'cuius' is /ku jus/, not /kwi us/ (and 'cui' is /ku i/ not /kwi:/).

Assuming this is the case, how did this slight difference come about? What prior terms led to the two different kinds of pronunciation? (eg maybe a genitive ending caused a sound change in the preceding vowel?)

Also, are there any cognate pairs in any other IE languages that exhibit this difference?

Comment: They're ultimately from the same basic root but the thing to realise is that *cuius*'s immediate ancestor is *quoius*, and when the *o* turned into *u* the *qu* became *c* through dissimilation. The *cu* isn't a variant of the *qu* in *quis*. (This is one of those instances where the fact that Latin's qu is /kʷ/ rather than /kw/ matters.)

Comment: @Cairnarvon it easily could have been 'quuius' /kʷu jus/ then, right?

Comment: The dissimilation involved is relatively mandatory, I think. Off-hand I can only think of one case where /kʷu/ didn't immediately turn into /ku/ and that's in *equus* (earlier *equos*), where it persisted through analogy with the oblique forms (and there's good evidence the actual pronunciation was often /ekus/ regardless). Even high frequency of use doesn't seem to encourage exception: when *quom*'s *o* turned into *u* the word universally became *cum* (with the spelling, but perhaps not the pronunciation, *quum* briefly existing), even though they already had a *cum* (from *com*).

Comment: @Cairnarvon That all seems like an answer.

Comment: Related: [What is the relationship between “cuius” and “quoius”](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/what-is-the-relationship-between-cuius-and-quoius)

Answer (score 3):

The initial *c* may actually be the easiest part of *cuius* to explain. As mentioned in the comments, the old spelling of the word is *quoius.* It was regular for *qu* (/kw/ or /kʷ/, depending on your theory of Latin phonology) to simplify to *c* /k/ before the vowel /u/. See [Why sequundus > secundus?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4901/why-sequundus-secundus)

Similar sound changes have applied in English to *wh-* words, cognate (as a general class) to Latin *qu-* words. *Wh* is replaced with /h/ in both spelling and pronunciation in *how,* and in pronunciation (although not spelling) in *who, whose,* because of the following /u/ (currently present as the vowel in *who, whose,* historically present but later diphthongized in *how*).

#### The etymology of the rest of *cuius*

The source of the *u* in *cuius* is I think usually considered to be raising of short /o/ to short /u/. This kind of raising occurs in various distinct contexts in Latin, such as in non-initial closed syllables (second-declension *-us* *-um* < *-os, -om*), before /ŋ/ (*[unguen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unguen)* < Proto-Italic *ongʷən), and before /l/ followed by another consonant (*[vulpes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vulpes)* < Proto-Italic *wolpis). I'm not sure however exactly what rule would cause raising in *quoius.*

I have seen an alternative account for the *u* that I don't think is currently accepted. A 1902 paper by Charles Exon, "The forms and scansion of the genitive and dative cases of is, hic, and qvi in Plautus"<sup>1</sup>, transcribes *huius* in Classical Latin with a long vowel in the first syllable ("hū-jus"), which is explained as deriving from "hoi-jus" by monophthongization of the original diphthong oi (pages 216, 218). (For the sound change, compare *ūnus* from Proto-Italic *oinos.) Exon applies the same explanation to *quoius > cuius.*

As far as I know, there is no direct evidence about the length of the vowel in *cuius,*<sup>2</sup> but it is usually thought to have been short, with the heavy scansion of the first syllable in Latin caused by a geminate (doubled) /jj/: /kujjus/ (or equivalently, [kʊjjʊs]). The source of that geminate consonant and the final /s/ are other complicated/difficult parts of the etymology of this word.

The pronunciation of *cui* also has some complications (mostly unrelated to the initial consonant). *Cui* has a monosyllabic pronunciation, which many sources describe as ending in a diphthong [ui̯] (or equivalently, a vowel-semivowel sequence [uj]). However, I think I remember reading some paper where the author argued that the monosyllabic pronunciation was actually identical to that of *qui.* I don't know whether this issue has been definitively settled.

---

1. *Hermathena,* Vol. 12, No. 28 (1902), pp. 208-233, accessed through JSTOR
2. The high /u/ in Spanish *cuyo,* which would in most contexts correspond to Latin long /uː/, can be explained as an effect of vowel raising caused by the following palatal, as in *huyo* < *fǔgio*: "Notes on Romanic Speech-History," by
   Edwin H. Tuttle, *The Modern Language Review,* Vol. 9, No. 4 (Oct., 1914), pp. 493-499.

   Tuttle says the /u/ in *cuius* is from uŏ, but I don't understand what he means.